# Making UITableviewCells deletable

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How are UITableView cells made to be able to be deleted by users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick example would be:

```
// create a mutable array to manage your table data
NSMutableArray *tableList;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tableList;
```

in your `viewDidLoad` method you can initialize it with data (you should check if `tableList` is nil first though)

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TableData" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

self.tableList = array; 
[array release];
```

then in the implementation file, you implement this delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row]; 
    [self.tableList removeObjectAtIndex:row]; 

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}
```

you can then toggle editing mode via

```
[self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:YES];
```

Comment: I had the arrays setup already. Implemented the delegate method. This worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the table view data source delegate method [`-tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:).

You override this method in your table view delegate (usually your table view controller) and put your deletion logic here.

For example, you can call a `UIAlertView` to ask the user to confirm the deletion, or just manipulate the data model directly, removing the object from your table view's data source.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to remove an item at e.g. index 4 of an array, will the array need to be resorted or will it be done automatically?
Regards

Comment: I'm trying to think of a case where you would need to resort after deleting an element of an array. Inserting, you may need to resort. Deleting, I'm not so sure.

Comment: Anyway, after changing your data source, you can call `[tableView reloadData]` or `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:... withRowAnimation:...]` to tell the table view to refresh its presentation from the data source. It is preferable to use the second option as it requires less work, but the first option is handy if you want to test things out.

Comment: I don't know what shifting negative means for an array. In any case, take a look at the `NSMutableArray` method `-removeObjectAtIndex:`: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_16

Comment: Yeah :D i deleted the comment as I saw IWasRobbed answer included the removeObjectAtIndex method. thanks.